# electron blank screen on raspberry pi 3b

Tags: raspberry-pi, electron, raspberry-pi3

I want to use electron js in order to build a desktop app, which will run on a Raspberry Pi 3B. I'm developing the app on my macbook. There, I can use the command `electron .` without any problems. If I try to start the electron-quick-start app, the following happens:

- I execute the following command in the terminal in the directory of electron-quick-start: `electron .`
- The electron window opens with the correct background color
- No html content is shown

I tried building the app with the electron-packager for the armv7l architecture and running it on the raspberry pi. This works, but it is a tedious task to build the app every time to test it on the Raspberry Pi.

Do you have any ideas, why the `electron .` command doesn't work?

UPDATE: I started debugging the main.js file:

```
webContents.on('did-start-loading', function() {
   console.log('did-start-loading');
});
webContents.on('did-stop-loading', function() {
   console.log('did-stop-loading');
});
webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
   console.log('did-finish-load');
});
webContents.on('did-get-response-details', function(e, status, newUrl) {
   console.log(newUrl);
});
```

And I get the following response:
   did start loading
   did stop loading

UPDATE 2:
I uncommented the `mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()` line, so actually the chromium dev tools should start, but they don't...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that the HTML content is loaded? That the window opened is prove that `electron .` started as it should so the error is probably the path here https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/main.js#L19-L23 or its a permission issue with the file or folder itselfe

Comment: @HansKoch Thanks for your response. It shouldn't be a problem with the loadURL or the permissions, as I have also tried loadURL('https://github.com') and it didn't work either. I had the same effect: the window openend and not html content was shown. Electron is still providing me events (for example the window move event), so it seems to run, but the loadURL command doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thats strange, you could try uncommenting https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/main.js#L26 and see if something in the renderer process is not working since the main process seams to work like intended

Comment: I also updated the post with some debugging results

Comment: @HansKoch I already uncommented that line and tried to open the dev tools (also via tab "View"->"Toggle Developer Tools"), but they don't get shown

Answer (score 1):

After the debugging and the fact, that the developer console wasn't working, I quickly came to the conclusion, that chromium is crashing.

I thereafter found this issue in the electron github repository:

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12850

It looks like the used version in the electron-quick-start demo (1.8.x) is not working on ARM processor. The version "2.0.0" works again.